# ThreadPool class: can't pass the args straight

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a Thread pool of the type that can be found [here](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool).

I try doing the following:

```
/* Allocate a ThreadPool */
shared_ptr<SpinTools::ThreadPool> pool(new SpinTools::ThreadPool(4));

/* Start processing each image in Core container */
for (int img_idx = 0; img_idx < num_images; img_idx++) {

    pool->enqueue(_worker_task, img_idx, _args, _stats);

}
```

My worker task has the following prototype:

```
void _worker_task(int img_idx, ProcessorArgs &args, Stats &stats)
```

however this won't compile and MSVC displays the error

```
Error   14  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::future<void> __cdecl ThreadPool::enqueue<void (__cdecl&)(int,struct ProcessorArgs,struct SpinCore::Features::Stats &),int &,struct Sift::ProcessorArgs &,struct SpinCore::Features::Stats &>(void (__cdecl&)(int,struct ProcessorArgs,struct SpinCore::Features::Stats &),int &,struct ProcessorArgs &,struct SpinCore::Features::Stats &)" (??$enqueue@A6AXHUProcessorArgs@Sift@@AEAUStats@Features@SpinCore@@@ZAEAHAEAU12@AEAU345@@ThreadPool@SpinTools@@QEAA?AV?$future@X@std@@A6AXHUProcessorArgs@Sift@@AEAUStats@Features@SpinCore@@@ZAEAHAEAU45@1@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl Sift::process(void)" (?process@Sift@@UEAAXXZ)
```

Edit: adding the header for ThreadPool::enqueue for completness:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
auto enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) 
    -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>;
```

Comment: did you modify `ThreadPool.h` file?

Comment: No. I included it in a namespace

Comment: what does *"I included it in a namespace"* mean ?

Comment: Encapsulated it within a namespace

Comment: can you show how you *"encapsulate"* this class in a namespace?

Comment: namespace Tools { class ThreadPool{...};}

Comment: did you do the same with `enqueue` member function? is it still in a header file?

Comment: @Arkadiy did you delete the answer? it was correct!

Comment: so you actually modified the file...

Comment: Because the implementation _was_ in the header? Or was I looking at check-in results? :)

Comment: That's why we place the information in the question, I guess.

Comment: the implementation was in the header allright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the implementation of ThreadPool::enqueue in the header. MSVC can't generate the implementation if it's in .cpp file only (or at least earlier versions could not)